# Making natbib and chapterbib work

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies)

I'm trying to write a book with references in each chapter and
I would like to use `chapterbib` and `natbib` packages.

I can't really understand how to make things work.

My book is organized as follows:

- `settings.tex` which contains all the packages, commands etc that I use in my document (among the others: `\usepackage{natbib}`, `\usepackage{chapterbib}`)
- `Chapter_01.tex` (in which I'd like the references stored in `references_01.bib`)
- `Chapter_02.tex` (in which I'd like the references stored in `references_02.bib`).

I then have a `Book.tex` file that is made like this:

```
\input{settings_pdf.tex}

\begin{document}

\include{Chapter_01.tex}

\include{Chapter_02.tex}

\end{document}
```

What should I put at the end of each chapter in order to get the references and how should I compile the document to produce a pdf document?

Comment: @lockstep: using natbib or not is not the same ...

Comment: @Herbert Comparing Gonzalo's and your answer the only difference is that you also recommend `bibtex <file>`. Maybe the linked question could be rewritten to be more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your structure is correct. You have to run `bibtex` for the document and each chapter:

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>
bibtex Chapter_01
bibtex Chapter_02
[...]
pdflatex <file>
pdflatex <file>
```

The first `bibtex` run will report an error `multiple bibdata commands`, which is not of interest, ignore it.

Comment: Herbert thanks, can you tell me how to include the specific bibliography at the end of each chapter?
I think that I make some mistakes there, because I use bibtex separately for each chapter...

Comment: Here you'll find example documents: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/LaTeX-Bib/02-03-1.ltx2  and also 02-03-2.ltx2 and 02-03-2.ltx3

Comment: It's TexStudio's problem.  I found that this hack lets TexStudio run bibtex on each included file:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/how-to-run-bibtex-in-texstudio-or-otherwise-on-included-files