# Bibliography by chapter with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, natbib, thesis

I have 3 articles that I need to assemble as a thesis. Each article has been written in Latex. Each article has a separate bibliography. Some of the references may overlap/repeat in each bibliography.

I need to use natbib for the bibliography since I have to use a particular bibliography style (lets call it "styleA"). I have looked for solutions online but I can only find info on solutions that rely on dropping natbib. I have been trying, without success, to do the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{StyleA}
\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\input{Chapter1.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter2.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter3.tex}

\end{document}
```

Each chapter calls on the following:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{bibliographyfile} % I change the filename of the bibliography at each chapter
```

So far I get the correct bibliography for Chapter 1, but then it repeats the same bibliography in chapters 2 and 3. Also, none of the non-overlaping references with those of chapter 1 get picked up (Latex reports question marks in chapters 2 and 3). Does anybody have any suggestions on how tohave a separate bibliography on each chapter with natbib? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add the option `[sectionbib]` to natbib.
- Add \usepackage{chapterbib}
- Change `\newpage \input{ }` to `\include{ }`
- Insert `\bibliographystyle{StyleA}` before each `\bibliography`
- Run *latex, run bibtex on each of the chapter files, run *latex, run *latex.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just tried running it but nothing changed. I am using TexStudio. I dont know how to run bibtex on each of the chapter files separately. I just have the option to run the main file. Do you know how I could do the last step?

Comment: It worked, I just had to remove ".tex" from the \include command. As for how to run bibtex in Texstudio, I leave this link here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/how-to-run-bibtex-in-texstudio-or-otherwise-on-included-files