# Multiple Bibliographies: Wrong bib-files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies)

I am working on the `tex` file for a journal in which several articles will be published.
I created a Master `tex` file, let's call it `master.tex`, that contains contents such as the titlepage, the imprint, the table of contents etc. For the sake of orginization I saved the articles in seperate `tex` files and include them in the master tex.

Every article has it's own bibliography `.bib`. The problem that arises is that at the end of an article (where I inserted the bibliography-command) a bibliography appears, however not the correct one. The first `bib` file that is inserted in the master `tex` appears on every position where a bibliography command is.

Can you help me out?

`master.tex`:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
% TITLEPAGE, IMPRINT, ...
\newpage
\include{author1}
\newpage
\include{author2}
\end{document}
```

whereas every article tex file has the same structure

`author1.tex`:

```
\section{heading}
% CONTENTS
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{author1}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that it is a job for the `bibunits` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{author1.bib}
@article{one,
  author = "Author1",
  title  = "Title1",
  year = 2011}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{author2.bib}
@article{two,
  author = "Author2",
  title  = "Title2",
  year = 2012}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}
\section{Author 1}
\cite{one}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\putbib[author1]
\end{bibunit}
\newpage


\begin{bibunit}
\section{Author 2}
\cite{two}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\putbib[author2]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

You have to run LaTeX first and then `bibtex buX` where `X` is the number of the bibunit, for each bibunit you have,  and finally compile with LaTeX (or whatever variant you use).