# How can I include a bibliography at the end of each part of a book?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to write a book divided into two parts. I'd like to insert a bibliography at the end of each part (several chapters each) but, since it will be one volume, I want the page number to keep growing. Is there a way to do it? I'm currently arguing with `chapterbib`, but I had no luck up to now. Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Welcome.  I think you should look at [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17480/15925) to a similar question.

Comment: My problem is a bit different: I have inserted citation throughout all the chapters but I need bibliography just at the end of the last. Furthermore I tried using \usepackage[gather]{chapterbib} but it makes me a page of reference for every chapter. I'm just looking for an environment like \thebibliography but where page number keeps growing after it.

Comment: Would you be willing to use [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) to create your bibliographies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies)

Comment: @egreg The solution in [Multiple bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies) does not work if one has multiple `\include`s (e.g., one for each chapter) but not the same number of bibliographies.

Answer (score 2):

`bibunits` (use `texdoc bibunits` for the manual) provides an alternative to `chapterbib`.

Here is a possible template for your use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\begin{document}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{bibunit}
\include{chapter1}
...
\include{chapterN}
\putbib[bibliography1]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}
\include{chapterN}
...
\include{chapterN+M}
\putbib[bibliography2]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

Then run

```
latex file
bibtex bu1
bibtex bu2
latex file
latex file
```

where `file` is the name of your master `.tex` file

Comment: I was trying exactly your solution but as soon as I latex the file the second time (I tried with just 1 bu) I get the error: "Can only be used in the preamble" making reference to \bibcite{citation}{1}. Any idea?

Comment: @Lorenzo No, I don't get errors.

Comment: The example works fine to me but in my file i get the error. I'm using both babel and hyperref do you know any issue?

Comment: `babel` and `hyperref` work for me (they might be problems with `hyperref` if a citation appears in both bibliography. Otherwise, no problems. Have you removed  existing auxiliary files?

Comment: Ok, I tried to load bibunits as the last package and now it give me no errors BUT where there should be the bibliography there are just [1] ... [6] (I have 18 references). I'm getting out for the blue...

Comment: Have you again removed all auxiliary files and run again `bibtex bu1` and `bibtex bu2`?  Alternatively you can try with `biblatex`.

Comment: Ok now it works, I found an error in my .bib file! =) One last thing do you know if there is any incompatibility with \boldmath and bibubits? I get the error (which I can skip, is not a big problem...)  "Math version 'BOLD' is not defined.

Comment: @Lorenzo Id doubt there are incompatibility between bibunits and \boldmath.