# Including additional bibliography (publication list) in thesis

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I have seen [Multiple bibliographies (cited references + list of publications)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/multiple-bibliographies-cited-references-list-of-publications) and [How can I include a bibliography at the end of each part of a book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87247/how-can-i-include-a-bibliography-at-the-end-of-each-part-of-a-book) but could find an answer.

I am writing a thesis where there is an overall bibliography. Plus, I want to make a separate list of my own publications. I tried exactly this: http://memming.isloco.com/ but somehow a bibliography list is not created. Can you please tell, how can I make a separate publication list.

I am using university provided thesis, which includes `natbib`, so I am not sure if I can use other packages.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/biblatex-list-of-references-of-own-papers-in-appendix-might-intersect-with-bib - also contains a working answer with `refsection` and `\nocite{*}`

Comment: If you are using Texmaker then the following link has a simple answer http://deparkes.co.uk/2015/06/30/latex-thesis-publications-list/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would make a seperate LaTeX document for it, and then just include the resulting bibliography. You second document, let's say `myrefs.tex` might look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% whatever you need here, basically a good idea is to use your real thesis header
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{myrefbibfile}
\end{document}
```

Now you compile this by standard sequence `latex`+`bibtex`+`latex`+`latex`. In your real thesis you add the following:

```
\begingroup
\def\refname{List of my Publications}
\def\bibname{List of my Publications}
\input{myrefs.bbl}
\endgroup
```

This should add the bibliography from the second document into the first one, and the name of the chapter/section should be `List of my Publications`. Note that we could surely omit one of the two almost identical lines, and change `\def` to `\renewcommand` in the one we keep, but since different classes use `\refname` or `\bibname`, we better keep both lines to make things work robustly.

Comment: Thanks. It gives the same number to my papers as in the BIG bibliography. It would be good, if it gives 1, 2 .... numbers. Can you please help.

Comment: I could solve that also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For document classes `book` and `report`, you need `\renewcommand\bibname{List of my Publications}` instead of `\renewcommand\refname{List of my Publications}`.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to do so is to use the biblatex package! You can put libraries where you want. You should read the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)!

#### Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    url=false,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex} % Load the package with some options.
\addbibresource{/Users/Phil/Documents/Bibliothek/library.bib} % This is your library.

\begin{document}

% Print your own papers.
\begin{refsection}
% If you print a bibliography within this section, only citations within this refsection will be printed.

% Option 1: Make nocite for all of your papers.
% Options 2 would be a seperate file which contains all of your papers.
\nocite{Springer2011}
\defbibnote{myPrenote}{
    Some words before I show you the list of my own papers.
}
\defbibnote{myPostnote}{
    A bunch of papers are still in print and not yet published.
}
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={Author's Contributions},
    prenote=myPrenote,
    postnote=myPostnote
]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{First Chapter}
Some Text with reference \cite{Madelung1991}.

\chapter{Second Chapter}
Some more Text with reference \cite{Einstein1905a}.

% Here we print the overall bibliography form the rest of the document.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want your publications inside a section (instead of creating a new chapter). The answers I found did not satisfy my needs. Thus, I post my research. Contents of MainFile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}      %bibliography format
\usepackage{bibtopic}

\textwidth 17cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5cm
\evensidemargin -0.5cm
\textheight 20cm
\parindent 0cm
\newcommand*{\bibref}[1]{\citealt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{State of the art}
\bibref{John}
\bibref{Connor}

\section{Publications}

\begin{btSect}[unsrtnat]{publications}
%\hspace{1cm}\textbf{Published papers}
\begin{center}\textbf{Published papers}\end{center}
\btPrintNotCited
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}[unsrtnat]{publications2}
%\hspace{1cm}\textbf{Papers under review}
\begin{center}\textbf{Papers under review}\end{center}
\btPrintNotCited
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}[apalike]{bibliography} %sort alphabetically
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\btPrintCited
\end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

Then compile with something like:

```
pdflatex MainFile
bibtex MainFile1
bibtex MainFile2
bibtex MainFile3 #add if needed
pdflatex MainFile
pdflatex MainFile
```

The only thing is that I don't know how to cite only specific items, let's say I have the contents of publications.bib and publications2.bib in the same file and I want to cite only certain items in the first `btSect` and other items in the second `btSect`.

EDIT: I found a way to do that

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}      %bibliography format
\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage{xcolor} %to change text color

\textwidth 17cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5cm
\evensidemargin -0.5cm
\textheight 20cm
\parindent 0cm
\newcommand*{\bibref}[1]{\citealt{#1}} %cite item
\newcommand{\textwt}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}} %text not seen

\begin{document}

\chapter{State of the art}
\bibref{John}
\bibref{Connor}

\section{Publications}

\begin{btUnit} %needed to reset the cited items
  \begin{btSect}[unsrtnat]{publications} %order by appearance in text
    %\hspace{1cm}\textbf{Published papers}
    \begin{center}\textbf{Published papers}\end{center}
    \begin{NoHyper} %needed if you have hyperlinks to cited items
      \textwt{\bibref{mypub1}} %my published paper
    \end{NoHyper}
    \vspace{-1em} %adjust if needed
    \btPrintCited %print only cited items
  \end{btSect}
\end{btUnit}

\begin{btUnit} %needed to reset the cited items
  \begin{btSect}[unsrtnat]{publications} %order by appearance in text
    %\hspace{1cm}\textbf{Papers under review}
    \begin{center}\textbf{Papers under review}\end{center}
    \begin{NoHyper} %needed if you have hyperlinks to cited items
      \textwt{\bibref{mypub2}} %my published paper
    \end{NoHyper}
    \vspace{-1em} %adjust if needed
    \btPrintCited %print only cited items
  \end{btSect}
\end{btUnit}

\begin{btSect}[apalike]{bibliography}
  \chapter*{Bibliography}
  \btPrintCited %print John & Connor
\end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

You need to execute as many `bibtex MainFileX` as `btSect` sections. Where X is 1,2,3...

bibliography.bib contents:

```
@article{John,
title = "{T}he {T}erminator",
journal = "Robotics Engineering",
year = "1984",
author = "James Cameron"
}

@article{Connor,
title = "{T}erminator 2: {J}udgment {D}ay",
journal = "Robotics Engineering",
year = "1991",
author = "James Cameron"
}
```

publications.bib contents

```
@article{mypub1,
  title={{T}eletubbies},
  journal = "Entertainment Engineering",
  author={Me Myself},
  year={2016},
}

@article{mypub2,
  title={{T}eletubbies {R}eturns},
  journal = "Entertainment Engineering",
  author={Me Myself},
  year={2016},
}
```

Result:

[image: chapter1 with my publications]
[image: Bibliography]

Probably there is a more elegant solution, but that is mine.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!