# How can I create a second bibliography for unreferenced items?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing a literature study in LaTeX. There are some studies I excluded from the search results. I would like to create a second bibliography with items I excluded. Right now, I've got this:

```
\bibliography{./bib/references.bib}
```

I would like to have a section/chapter before called "Unreferenced articles", with a few articles I did not refer to. Worth mentioning is that these articles are listed in `./bib/references.bib` but if I refer to them, they will pop up in the normal bibliography as well, which is not what I want.

I know about `\nocite`, but that's not useful in this scenario. However, if something like this existed, that would be great:

```
\nocite[unreferenced]{66, 142, 143}
```

to have articles 66, 142 and 143 pop up only in the *Unrefernced Articles* section and not show up in *Bibliography*.

Comment: Please provide a proper minimal example, complete with sample `.bib` entries, which people can compile and play with. This will also clarify your bibliographic management software. It would be helpful to note whether you are willing to change this, if such a change would facilitate a solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the `multibib` package? It lets you set up two separate bibliographies. Have you consulted the [Multiple bibliographies?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/FAQ-multbib.html) entry at the [UK TeX FAQ website](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/index.html)?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `biblatex`, things are quite straight forward:

First, add `keywords = {unreferenced}` to the .bib-file entries of the items that you want to appear in the second bibliography.

Then use the following code to print the two bibliographies:

```
\printbibliography[notkeyword=unreferenced]
\printbibliography[keyword=unreferenced,title=Unreferenced Articles]
```

---

Having thought a bit about it, another possibility that does not entail updating your bibfile every time you change something would be to use two refsections:

```
\begin{document}
\newrefsection

Text and normal citations go here.

\printbibliography
\newrefsection
\nocite{everything you did not cite above}
\printbibliography[title=Unreferenced Articles]
```

Comment: PITA to maintain: you have to manually pick through everything classifying the entries and, if you reference something new or remove a reference, you have to change the `.bib` entry.

Comment: The automatic `biblatex` solution would be [How to split bibliography into “works cited” and “works not cited”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864)

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt my solution to [Including additional bibliography (publication list) in thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/including-additional-bibliography-publication-list-in-thesis/97059#97059)

Make a seperate LaTeX document, and then just include the resulting bibliography. You second document, let's say `nocite.tex` might look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% whatever you need here, basically a good idea is to use your original header/preamble
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\nocite{66,142,143}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{bibliofile}
\end{document}
```

Now you compile this by standard sequence `latex`+`bibtex`+`latex`+`latex`. In your real document you can add the following:

```
\begingroup
\def\refname{List of my Publications}
\def\bibname{List of my Publications}
\input{nocite.bbl}
\endgroup
```

This should add the bibliography from the second document into the first one, and the name of the chapter/section should be `List of my Publications`. Note that we could surely omit one of the two almost identical lines, and change `\def` to `\renewcommand` in the one we keep, but since different classes use `\refname` or `\bibname`, we better keep both lines to make things work robustly.

The drawback is that if you actually cite something that's also included in your `nocite.tex`, it will appear in both bibliographies. So basically consider this as a starting point; I hope someone will provide a better solution.