# Chapterbib is working but keeps giving me errors. Any way to silence it?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors, subdividing

I'm using Chapterbib to write my bibliography separately after each chapter. It does work but bibtex is still giving me plenty of errors and warnings:

```
Illegal, another \bibstyle command
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command.

Illegal, another \bibdata command
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command.

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "druhy".
```

etc. Basically I'm getting 2 error messages per file and 1 warning message per citation. Since the final publication will be quite large, I'd rather not have tens of errors and hundreds of warnings when I compile it all together. Is there any way around it? I'd be happy with just silencing these particular error and warning messages. I did follow the instructions for the build order (latex, bibtex on individual files, latex, latex).

Minimal working example:

**Test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

**Chapter1.tex**

```
blabla \cite{prvni}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{jedna}
```

**Chapter2.tex**

```
bleble \cite{druhy}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{dva}
```

**jedna.bib**

```
@article{prvni,
author = "A. Aa",
title = "blahblah",
year = "2000",
journal = "tojefuk"
}
```

**dva.bib**

```
@article{druhy,
author = "B. Bb",
title = "blehbleh",
year = "2001",
journal = "tojejedno"
}
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce the error, but [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies) looks like it might be helpful.

Comment: Try removing *all* auxiliary files first.

Comment: Did you really run  bibtex separatly on the aux-files of the included files (correct) or also on the aux-file of the main file (wrong)?

Comment: @Crissov: Tried that but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: @alexwlchan: I'm using TeXnicCenter for building my .pdf files and TeXworks for building bibliographies if it makes any difference.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, I used TexnicCenter on test.tex, then I used TeXworks and built the chapter1.aux and chapter2.aux files with BibTeX and followed with TexnicCenter, building test.tex twice again.

Comment: This example compiles fine for me.  It may be simplest if you could use/install latexmk and use that - I knows how to cope with this situation.

Comment: Do you use some build profile from TeXnicCenter which includes a bibtex run?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You were right! The default build profile that I used did build the bibtex as well. I'm getting no more errors or warnings once I turned it off. Many many thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to a build profile in TeXnicCenter, which included a run of `bibtex` on the main file.  Turning off this profile removes the error messages.

Comment: I am having this issue in Overlead. How can I go about "Turning off this profile" in overleaf?

Comment: @Daniel I suggest contacting the overleaf staff via their link in help.