# number and author year style in a single file with natbib package

Tags: natbib, subdividing

Is it possible to get both the numbered and the author-year citation style in a single book by using the `natbib` package?

I need one chapter with numbered and another chapter with author-year style. Is it possible to get the output by using the natbib package?

Comment: Why both styles in the same book?

Comment: Will there be a separate bibliography for each chapter?

Comment: Is the natbib package mandatory or is another package also fine?

Comment: Which journal is it? Journals do not do this. A journal has a style and authors' articles are laid out according to that style so that the finished product has a consistent look. Similarly, most book publishers have standard styles they use. Certainly, a single style would be used for all chapters in an anthology, and usually for all books in a series or whatever.

Comment: You need to use a package to support the production of multiple bibliographies.

Comment: `bibunits` can do this but I've deleted my answer because ti does not allow numerical + author-year if `natbib` is used.

Comment: I think the `chapterbib` package can do this.  See [Multiple bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17474) for an example.

Comment: @AlanMunn Feel free to copy my example. I was just curious about how this would work because I'd tried to get `chapterbib` working in this way before and failed. You should answer, though.

Comment: @cfr If your answer works, I would just undelete it and be done with it.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK. Well, tell me if you change your mind. It worked with my MWE. I don't know whether it will work for the OP given the lack of MWE.

Answer (score 2):

This uses [Alan Munn's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209462/number-and-author-year-style-in-a-single-file-with-natbib-package#comment517572_209462) in a comment on the question. I'd tried `chapterbib` before but got errors, even using the documentation for `natbib`. However, experimentation suggests the following should work:

```
\begin{filecontents}{f1.tex}
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \citestyle{plainnat}
  References to an article, \cite{article-full},
  and to an entire journal, which appears
  only in the references\nocite{whole-journal}.
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{f2.tex}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \citestyle{plain}
  A new chapter with a different style and a cite
  of some possibly interesting proceedings, \cite{proceedings-full}.
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\begin{document}
  \include{f1}
  \include{f2}
\end{document}
```

Note that various things seem to be crucial here. In particular, you need to issue `\citestyle{}` which was not obvious to me from the documentation. In particular, you need to do this even when you want to use the `plainnat` style and even when you've just issued `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. At least, without this, I could not get the correct format to be used.

[image: author-year and numerical chapter-by-chapter]