# Question marks instead of citations when using \include

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have been struggling a lot with this problem now. Hopefully somebody can help me.
I want to create a document with chapterwise bibliography, so I use \usepackage{chapterbib} together with \usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

where the file chapter1.tex (in the same folder) is

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
this is chapter 1~\cite{Article1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
```

and the file references.bib (also in the same folder) reads

```
@article{Article1,
    author = {Author1},
    journal = {J. Art.},
    pages = {1906--1911},
    title = {{This is the first article}},
    volume = {12},
    number = {3},
    year = {2012}
}
```

While the second citation (Article2) is displayed as expected, there is a question mark where the first citation should be: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhtuz9nw0otuw6i/Include.pdf?dl=0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I forgot to mention: It does work if you substitude \include by \input. But then, chapterbib does not work anymore.

Comment: you should use `\include`  with all the chapters and run bibtex separately on each chapter to generate the  separate bibliographies

Comment: This is what I have done several times. Does not seem to work.

Comment: If you have a version that you think should work but does not, edit the question above to be that code (so move `\chapter` out of the main file) and then say exactly how it "does not work" show exactly how you called bibtex and what error log you got

Comment: So I removed \chapter from the main file and everything that has to do with it. I called bibtex from TeXstudio (via the Tools menu) in both TEX files.
I just found that I get an error message already at that point, saying: "Illegal, another \bibdata command". This problem is thus comparable to that given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies.
However, other than described there I wasn't able to get to any better result yet. The final pdflatex compilation keeps giving above-mentioned result and the message: Illegal, another \bibdata command
I'm workin on it.

Comment: I found the problem now. I didn't know that TeXstudio uses bibtex always on the main document, even if chapter1.tex is active. I had to run bibtex via the command window to make it work. Strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wonder why i still bother answering questions, when crossposting is so popular. http://golatex.de/fehlermeldung-illegal-another-bibstyle-command-t16494.html

Comment: This hack lets TexStudio run bibtex on each included file:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/how-to-run-bibtex-in-texstudio-or-otherwise-on-included-files

Answer (score 4):

You should use `\include` with all the chapters and run bibtex separately on each chapter to generate the separate bibliographies, one for each chapter.

Comment: This is what I have done several times. Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my LaTeX editor, TeXstudio, does not run bibtex on the active document, but always on the main document. However, bibtex must be run on the sub-document to generate (what was in my case called) chapter1.bbl.
Running bibtex via the command window solved the problem.

Comment: If you happen to use texlive (and not miktex) then compiling on the code with `latexmk - pdf master.tex` ought to run bibtex automatically on each separate part

Comment: Great hint! But not miktex? Is says "because it is part of MacTeX and MikTeX" on https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html